# Flutter Pub Get command fails to add dependencies

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was working on a flutter project and when I try to add new packages or assets to the pubspec.yaml file and try to add the dependencies with "flutter pub get" command the process doesn't finish with the exit code 0.
I'm using VSCode.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

A:\Docs\Flutter\messenger>flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in messenger...                           0.7s

A:\Docs\Flutter\messenger>
```

Also if I ignore on getting the exit code the dependencies do not reflect in my code with a error message quoting

```
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist
```

I have also tried the get packages button but it's no good too. This issue also happens to assets when I try to add assets

```
  assets:
    - assets\images\
```

it show a similar error code

```
The asset assets\images\ does not exist.
Try creating the file or fixing the path to the file.
```

Comment: The indentation is critical in `pubspec.yaml`. Everything is aligned using `spaces` and not `tabs`. Check for indentation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when pub get gives error, it's something else that gives the error and not the actual 'pub get' command. Please make sure you don't have any errors in your project before running 'pub get' command. As you have not given enough information, it is hard to provide more options that may help you. Please show your codes/flutter doctor if you need more assistance.